# Doctrine 2: Define entity constants in yaml

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to add constants to my Doctrine2 entities. My entities get generated out of a yaml definition. (So if I add constants manually to my .php entity files they get deleted the next time I generate entities.)

Is there a way to define constants within yaml? Doctrine2 seems to support this feature just by using annotations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is possible with Symfony 3.2+, see http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files